# Does the sh command use the users shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh, command-line-interface

Does the `sh` linux command use the users current shell, even if its not `bash`? For example, let's say the user bob is running csh. If I create a script with functions and csh and try and execute it with:

```
sh cshtestscript
```

Will this run with csh?

Then assume another use joe is using bash. If I create another script with functions and bash script and try and execute it with:

```
sh bashtestscript
```

Will this run with bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sh` is just a standard executable, which is always a specific shell. There is no magic to detect which shell to use.

```
% whereis sh
sh: /bin/sh
% ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 29 11:53 /bin/sh -> dash
```

On Ubuntu systems, `/bin/sh` is (by default) a symlink to [dash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dash.1.html), which is a minimal POSIX shell intended for non-interative use. If you run `sh cshtestscript` on an Ubuntu system, it will try to run the script with dash.

The correct way to handle this is to add a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the script which indicates which shell to use, make the script executable, and always execute it as `./cshtestscript`.

```
#!/bin/csh
```

Comment: Yeah, basically I am looking for a way to run these scripts without actually creating files. So something like: `sh echo "#!/bin/bash free -m"`. Would that work?

Comment: @Justin Just use `bash -c 'free -m'`